# Elementary Os live CD retrieve a secondary monitor that doesn't exist

Tags: graphics, elementary-os

I was trying eOS on an ASUS laptop (note: this laptop has got a double graphic card intel+nvidia) and I've noticed that the os retrieve a secon monitor that does not exist!

Then I tried to disable it from the monitor configuration but after a while it returns exactly as it was before.

Someone had had the same problem? It's only a live CD problem ot this is a known bug? I had read something relative googling around but no practical solution or explanation...

Comment: what problem are you having?

Comment: I see a second monitor that does not exist. When I open an application (for example Midori) it appears in this "fake" monitor and I can't see it.